# Using cert-manager for self signed certificates in Rancher

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, rancher, cert-manager

I'm using Rancher for my PoC. As part of stack I'm using harbor as helm chart registry and container registry. I'm following [this tutorial](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/installation/install-rancher-on-k8s/chart-options/#additional-trusted-cas) about how to configure self signed certificate in Ranchor for Harbor in this case.

I'm interested about how to use cert-manager for managing self-signed certificate in any cluster in Rancher. Currently cert-manager is running in rancher cluster (because rancher is using self-signed certificate too). Have I install cert-manager in all of my clusters in which I need to have an integration with Harbor. Since certificate is currently not configured, I'm always getting that error [x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/installation/resources/custom-ca-root-certificate/).

Answer (score 0):

Check if, in the context of your tutorial, the page "[Updating a Private CA Certificate](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/installation/resources/update-ca-cert/)"

It includes "Reconfigure Rancher agents to trust the private CA"

> For each cluster under Rancher management (except the `local` Rancher management cluster) run the following command using the `Kubeconfig` file of the Rancher management cluster (RKE or K3S).
>
> ```
> kubectl patch clusters.management.cattle.io <REPLACE_WITH_CLUSTERID> \
> -p '{"status":{"agentImage":"dummy"}}' --type merge
> ```
>
> This command will cause all Agent Kubernetes resources to be reconfigured with the checksum of the new certificate.